# What makes each filter/kernel of a CNN learn different weights?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, conv-neural-network

Say we have N number of filters in a Conv Layer of a CNN. Each filter will learn different weights in order to detect different patterns of the image, so the loss function is finally minimized, but **what** mechanism of the network is the one that ensures (up to an extent I guess) that convolution kernels do not learn the same weights?

The same question but from other perspective would be:

When a learning step is made in the CNN, what makes the gradients of two different kernels to be different so that the weight adjustment is not the same so the two kernels end up being different?